# If custom field exists, echo image with URL of custom field

Tags: php

Doesn't work, I get get unexpected T_STRING

```
 <?php $customfield = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bannerurl', true);
    if ($customfield == '') { 
        echo '<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bannerurl', true); ?>" alt="text" />'; 
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: Remember: SO is _not a debug tool_

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo You're false - `Specific programming problems` also means debugging

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Please read [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page

Comment: don't care I'm using it as one

Answer (score 1):

Try like below:

```
   //if $customfild exist than below will execute else "No Data".
    if (isset($customfield)) { 
    echo '<img src="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bannerurl', true).'" alt="text" />'; }
    else
     echo "No Data";
```

Comment: that's working but how do I make it return nothing if the custom field doesn't exist?

Comment: before if () condition can you do like print_r($customfield) and see what values are coming.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php $customfield = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bannerurl', true);
    if ($customfield == '') { 
        echo '<img src="get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bannerurl', true)" alt="text" />'; 
     }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($customfield == '') { 
echo '<img src="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bannerurl', true).'" alt="text" />'; }
```

To check if `$customfield` exists use `isset()` method - you can read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).